# FlexSlider not loading any properties (slideshow, animation, loop)

Tags: jquery, flexslider

I have flexslider loaded on my website here: https://reach.med.fsu.edu/

The slides are there and I can scroll through them, but I can't seem to get it to auto animate.  Putting slideshow:true, has no effect.  No matter what property I enter it doesn't seem to have any effect.

This is what I have in my head

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(window).load(function() {
        $('.flexslider').flexslider({
            animationLoop: true,
            slideshow: true,
            slideshowSpeed: 1000,})

    });
</script>
```

When I put these lines of code in the head as instructed by WooCommerce, the slider disappears completely

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(window).load(function() {
        $('.flexslider').flexslider({
            animationLoop: true,
            slideshow: true,
            slideshowSpeed: 1000,})

    });
</script>
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong, any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You have error on console  ` at tz_format_twitter (jquery.tweet.js:3)` . First fix that error or disable tweet.js and see what happen ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to fix the at tz_format_twitter error but could not track down what was causing it.  Upon doing so I found conflicting code in my jquery.js code that was negating the stuff I included in the head.  That seems to have fixed it.